# JavaScript: Multiple Facts in an Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I try to Code my own Alexa Skill. Its a Basic Fact - Skill.

I have some Data:

```
const data = [
    'FACT1',
    'FACT2',
    'FACT2',
];
```

And I have the Value (how many Facts):

```
var VALUE = this.event.request.intent.slots.Number.value;
```

How do I return X Facts (=VALUE) in ONE String? (So I can give the Facts back)
I assume, i have to use a for-Loop, so something like this:

```
'MulitpleFacts': function(){
        const factArr = data;

        var VALUE = this.event.request.intent.slots.anzahl.value;
        var i;

        for (var i = 0; i <= VALUE; i++){


        }

    },
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is your required output ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result that looks like `FACT1, FACT2`, use `data.slice(...).join()`

```
'MulitpleFacts': function(){
    const factArr = data;

    var VALUE = this.event.request.intent.slots.anzahl.value;
    var result = data.slice(0, VALUE).join(', ');

},
```

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I was searching for. Thank you!